# Broke up over sized class, now getting segue error [swift]

Tags: ios, class, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

So to break up my 4000 line `View Controller` class, I decided to make another class.
This is the separate class I created in a new swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class NewClass {

var vc = ViewController()

    func switcher1test() {
        switch numberSwitchCase1 {
        case 0:
            println("stuff goes here")
        default:
            vc.callToSegue()
        break
    }
  }
}
```

This switch case function, in my original class, worked fine (without the vc. of course)
This is where it is now being called from inside my original class.

```
func switcher1() {
    var newClass = NewClass()
    newClass.switcher1test()
}
```

When the switch case function is in placed here (in the original class, without the call to the new class obviously), everything works fine.

The callToSegue() calls this segue in my original class

```
func callToSegue() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UnwindSegue", sender: self)
}
```

This is where the error hits. Here is the error.

```
2015-03-20 00:58:20.342 MYAPP[7451:181575] *** Terminating app     due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MYAPP.ViewController: 0x7c8f8400>) has no segue with identifier 'UnwindSegue''
```

Now I know for a fact the identifier is hooked up correctly, because like I said, before I moved my switch case, it worked fine, and when I put my switch case back in for testing, it still works.

It's only when I have it in a separate class do I get this crash.

For clarification, the switch case function it self works properly when in the new class, it's only when I hit the `callToSegue()` `performSegueWithIdentifier`, which is located on the original class, do I get the crash.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line

```
var vc = ViewController()
```

you create a new instance of the viewController, which is probably not what you want.

Create a protocol and let your viewController be the delegate for your `NewClass`:

```
protocol SegueProtocol {
    func callToSegue()
}
```

The ViewControllerClass must conform to that protocol

```
class MyViewController: SegueProtocol {
    ...
    func callToSegue() {
        ...
    }
}
```

NewClass gets the delegate for MyViewController:

```
class NewClass {
    ...
    var delegate: SegueProtocol?

    func switcher1test() {
        switch numberSwitchCase1 {
        case 0:
            println("stuff goes here")
        default:
            // call the delegate
            self.delegate?.callToSegue()
        break
    }
  }
}
```

When NewClass is instantiated (within MyViewController), set the ViewController as the delegate:

```
func switcher1() {
    var newClass = NewClass()
    newClass.delegate = self   // self is the viewController here
    newClass.switcher1test()
}
```

Comment: You rock!!! Seriously man you saved me from a major headache. I also just had to add an init() { } to the NewClass, and everything is working great! Major thanks and much appreciation!